# How is a large dataset uploaded to a cloud file system (S3, HDFS) if there isn't enough space on local disk?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr

I have a project that deals with processing data with Spark on EMR.

From what I've read, people usually store their input data on some file system (HDFS, S3, or locally), and then operate on that. If the data is very large, we don't want to store that locally.

My question is, if I generate a bunch of data, how do you even store that data remotely on S3 or whichever cloud file system there is in the first place? Don't I need to have the data stored locally before I can store it on the cloud?

I ask this because currently, I'm using a service that has a method that returns a Spark `Dataset` object to me. I'm not quite sure how the workflow goes between calling that method and processing it via Spark on EMR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object store connectors tend to write data in blocks; for each partition the work creates a file through the Hadoop FS APIs, with a path like  `s3://bucket/dest/__temporary/0/task_0001/part-0001.csv`, gets back an output stream into which the workers write, that's it.

I don't know about the closed source EMR s3 connector, the ASF S3A one is up there for you to examine

1. Data is buffered up to the value of `fs.s3a.blocksize`; default = `32M, i.e. 32MB
2. Buffering is to disk (default), Heap (arrays) or off-heap byte buffers [S3ADataBlocks](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3ADataBlocks.java#L83).
3. When you write data, once the buffer threshold is reached, that block is uploaded (separate thread); a new block buffer created. [S3ABlockOutputStream.write](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3ABlockOutputStream.java#L276).
4. when the stream's `close()` method is called, any outstanding data is PUT to S3, then then thread blocks until it is all uploaded. [S3ABlockOutputStream.close](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3ABlockOutputStream.java#L346)

The uploads are in a separate thread, so even if the network is slow you can generate data slightly faster, with the block at the end. The amount of disk/ram you need is as much as all outstanding blocks from all workers uploading data. The thread pool for the upload is shared and of a limited size, so you can tune the params to limit these values. Though that's normally only needed if you try to buffer in memory.

When the queue fills up, the worker threads writing to the S3 output stream block, via the [SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java).

the amount of local storage you need then depends on:

- number of spark worker threads
- rate of data they generate
- number of threads/http connections you have to upload the data
- bandwidth from VM to S3 (the ultimate limit)
- any throttling S3 does with many clients writing to same bit of a bucket

That's with the S3A connector; the EMR s3 one will be different, but again, upload bandwidth will be the bottleneck. I assume it too has something to block workers which create more data than the network can handle.

Anyway: for Spark and the hadoop code it uses underneath, all the source is there for you to explore. Don't be afraid to do so!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with Spark and any distributed storage keep in mind, that there is some amount of nodes in the Spark cluster.

While the `Dataset` transformations are manipulated from the single node of cluster named `driver`, common practice is that all processed data never get collected on one single node in such a cluster. Each node of `executor` role in cluster operates with fraction of whole data during its ingestion into Spark, processing and storing back to some kind of storage.

With such approach the limits of single node do not limit the volume of data that could be processed by cluster.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. However, does the data that is processed have to be stored locally before being stored in S3 (and then retrieved by the driver node)?

Comment: In general Spark stores data in memory on executors into serialized form. It is possible to cache data also on disk storage of each node if it's requested by user.